# CONTAINS statement in COGNOS

Tags: if-statement, expression, contains, cognos

what I am trying to accomplish is as follows:

- I am trying to have an expression that returns a value "A" if 'apple' is anywhere in the string, and return value "B" if 'bell' is anywhere in the string.
- if 'apple' or 'bell' is not in the string, then 'null'

eg, the column will have 'apple', 'bell', 'any other word' at different positions in the string and I need a formula that returns "A" if 'apple' in present and "B" if 'bell' is present

column value example:

- 'applebee'
- 'appletart'
- 'bellview'
- 'bellmont'
- 'apple fritter'
- 'freedom bell'
- 'bird'
- 'coffin'
- '...'

desired outcome:

- "A"
- "A"
- "B"
- "B"
- "A"
- "B"
- "null"
- "null"
- "null"

i have tried:

- [description] contains 'INV' then 1
  [description] contains 'VOL' then 2
  else 'null'

maybe an if statement could work better?

Comment: And what would you do with the values "apple bell" and "bell apple"?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try:

```
if(lower([description]) contains 'apple') then ('A') else
if (lower([description]) contains 'bell') then ('B') else 
(Null)
```

Comment: A case function might be clearer but that's on the right track.